# Mermory issue by using a for loop in R of C++ function using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

there is something unclear by using for loop with Rcpp function. here is a simple example that should help:

This is my cpp code in file `test_cpp.cpp`

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat test_Cpp(int n,
                   arma::vec my_vec,
                   Rcpp::List my_list,
                   int mat_size,
                   double lambda,
                   double beta) {
  //  Matrix of mat_size rows & mat_size columns (filled with 0)
  arma::mat matrix_out(mat_size, mat_size) ;
  for (int it = 0 ; it < n ; ++it) {
    arma::mat temp_mat_flux_convol = my_list[it] ;
    if (my_vec[it] != 0) {
      matrix_out += lambda * my_vec[it] * beta * temp_mat_flux_convol ;
    }
  }
  return matrix_out ;
 }
```

Then from the R code why `res1` and `res2` are different when used in a 'useless' for loop and the same without for loop? I guess there is a segfault stuff, but I did not get it!

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
sourceCpp(file = "src/test_cpp.cpp")
set.seed(123)
ls_rand = lapply(1:10, function(x) matrix(rnorm(9), ncol=3))


for(i in 1:1){
  res1 <- test_Cpp(n = 10,
                my_vec = 1:100,
                my_list = ls_rand,
                mat_size = 3,
                lambda =  24,
                beta = 0.4)

  res2 <- test_Cpp(n = 10,
                my_vec = 1:100,
                my_list = ls_rand,
                mat_size =  3,
                lambda = 24,
                beta = 0.4)
}
all.equal(res1, res2)
res1 ; res2 # here res2 is twice res1 !!!

## Without for loop
res1 <- test_Cpp(n = 10,
                my_vec = 1:100,
                my_list = ls_rand,
                mat_size = 3,
                lambda =  24,
                beta = 0.4)
res2 <- test_Cpp(n = 10,
              my_vec = 1:100,
              my_list = ls_rand,
              mat_size =  3,
              lambda = 24,
              beta = 0.4)

all.equal(res1, res2)
res1 ; res2 # here res1 and res2 are the same!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies here:

```
  //  Matrix of mat_size rows & mat_size columns (filled with 0)
  arma::mat matrix_out(mat_size, mat_size) ;
```

The [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) says:

> mat(n_rows, n_cols)       (memory is not initialised)
>    mat(n_rows, n_cols, fill_type)     (memory is initialised)

So if you change your code to

```
  //  Matrix of mat_size rows & mat_size columns (filled with 0)
  arma::mat matrix_out(mat_size, mat_size, arma::fill::zeros) ;
```

The comment is actually right and the problem goes away.

Comment: Yes. Fantastic. I banged my head against a wall a all day long!